# in Python does 'or not' has 'not' precencence or 'or' precedence?

Tags: python, operators, operator-precedence

first time asking for help here.

I going through Kaggle' Python exercises and on Booleans section there is this example:

```
prepared_for_weather = have_umbrella or rain_level < 5 and have_hood or not rain_level > 0 and is_workday
```

They say that to make the code more readable it helps using parenthesis this way:

```
prepared_for_weather = have_umbrella or (rain_level < 5 and have_hood) or not (rain_level > 0 and is_workday)
```

I am confused about why (considering that the order of operator's precendence in not, and, or) at the end of the expression the **and** after **rain_level > 0** had higher precendence than the **not** before it.

Is it because the **not** should be considerate as **'or not'** so having less precence than the **and**?

I hope this is clear enough, thanks!

Having read on Python's documentation that the oerder of precedence is not, and, or I expected the **not** just before rain_level > 0 to have higher precendence than the **and** after it.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: first one, without braces, is the same as `prepared_for_weather = have_umbrella or (rain_level < 5 and have_hood) or ((not rain_level > 0) and is_workday)` i.e. it's not just readability

Comment: I would understand that! but on Kaggle it says that it can be written as 'prepared_for_weather = have_umbrella or ((rain_level < 5) and have_hood) or (not (rain_level > 0 and is_workday))' making the last **and** operator having precedence on the *not*.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), `not x` has precedence over `and`

The suggested expression with braces "for readability" is not equivalent to first one, e.g.

```
have_umbrella = False
have_hood = False
is_workday = False
rain_level = 3


# first
prepared_for_weather = have_umbrella or rain_level < 5 and have_hood or not rain_level > 0 and is_workday
print(prepared_for_weather)

# Kaggle's
prepared_for_weather = have_umbrella or (rain_level < 5 and have_hood) or not (rain_level > 0 and is_workday)
print(prepared_for_weather)

# mine from comments
prepared_for_weather = have_umbrella or rain_level < 5 and have_hood or ((not rain_level > 0) and is_workday)
print(prepared_for_weather)
```

output

```
False
True
False
```

Comment: Thanks, I also though your expression is right. I am not sure why here [link](https://www.kaggle.com/code/colinmorris/booleans-and-conditionals?scriptVersionId=79384617&cellId=17) they format it this way.

Comment: You really need to ask them and/or flag the bug/problem